# Error in labelling the name of the columns using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array of data of (31,1)

```
df

array([-4.92986060e-01, -3.26816435e-01, -2.81509125e-02, -5.50369198e-02,
   -4.78291735e-01, -3.77629735e-01,  2.56439110e-01, -7.80681558e-02,
    1.16469866e-01,  3.85537902e-02,  1.45576290e-02,  1.30638731e-01,
   -1.38000533e-01,  1.59521248e-02, -5.90236009e+00, -1.93493371e+00,
    9.29390668e-02,  1.58132616e-01, -2.37706974e-01,  4.10766116e-01,
   -1.99106536e-02,  2.91439759e-03, -1.34659982e+00, -8.83233098e-02,
   -1.19043573e-01, -1.98791078e-02,  2.18003752e-03,  7.97191732e-03,
    5.01870085e-02,  8.15185865e-02,  3.56969073e-02])
```

I am trying to label each value with its header by using `pd.dataframe`

```
df = pd.DataFrame (df,  columns=[feature_names])
```

but it shows that the data dimensions I was trying to imply is (31,31)

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (31, 1), indices imply (31, 31)
```

Comment: The shape of your list should be the same. It seems like you have your dataframe with shape (31,1) and your columns (1,31), which gives you the error. Just reshape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it a list

```
df = pd.DataFrame ([df],  columns=[feature_names])
```

Answer (score 1):

So I believe i know the reason. So you're df is an array of values and it's shape is (31,1) as in 31 rows and 1 column and does not have any feature_names, so when you're trying to create a DataFrame from it, you cannot use `columns=[feature_names]` as your df does not have any.

As a result you would have to specify a single column feature_name for your df :

`df = pd.DataFrame ([df],  columns=['feature_name'])`

If you want to have 31 columns and 1 row , you have to explictly reshape the array to (1,-1) and have a list of 31 feature names.

Hope this was helpful!